# Can you create inset drop-shadows in CSS?

Tags: css

I have an `<img>` tag with an image that contains some transparent parts. On top of that image, I want to display a kind of shadow to give it some depth. The critical part is that the shadow should be *inset* inside the image boundary, not around the image like a regular drop shadow.

I get a similar result as the one that I am looking for if I use the `box-shadow` property with the `inset` option, but that shadow falls on the rectangular content box around the image, totally ignoring the transparency in the image.

```css
img {
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 10px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://interactive-examples.mdn.mozilla.net/media/examples/firefox-logo.svg" width=100/>
```

I would use the `drop-shadow` filter which handles transparency in the image as desired, but I couldn't find any `drop-shadow` option equivalent to the `inset` option of `box-shadow`.

Answer (score -1):

Hello how's it going? Yes, you can, but you must use it with the SVG tag and not IMG. Below it's an example of how to do it, I hope it helps you.

[Firefox drop-shadow](https://codesandbox.io/embed/spring-frost-d1btie?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

If you want to know more, you can have a look at this link

[adding-shadows-to-svg-icons-with-css-and-svg-filters](https://css-tricks.com/adding-shadows-to-svg-icons-with-css-and-svg-filters/)

Comment: Thanks! Your example creates a drop shadow behind the image. That can also be done with the `drop-shadow` CSS filter directly on the `<img>` element. What I am looking for is an *inset* shadow, which means the it is on the inside of the image boundary instead of outside. But your points in the right direction. I found many explanations on the web of how to create such inset shadows in SVG graphics.